# CSV/Text file upload using node js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I need to create a function to upload CSV/txt file into mongodb using mean stack.

The function should be like i will upload a file. First it will check whether its in text/csv format than it will upload that to mongodb.

I searched on internet and couldnt find any good material. Anyone have any idea, Please share

Comment: What have you found so far.?

Answer (score 0):

I used `angular-file-upload` and wrote my own handler using `multiparty` for express.